# Spring Data Neo4j APOC not executing but no errors

Tags: java, spring-boot, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, neo4j-apoc

I am trying to use some Neo4j APOC procedures, mainly `apoc.periodic.commit` and `apoc.periodic.iterate` using the `@Query` annotation in a Spring Data Neo4j repository. The following query shall serve as an example:

```
@Query("CALL apoc.periodic.commit(\"MATCH (n:SomeNodeLabel)-[*]->(x) WHERE ID(n) = {id} DETACH DELETE x RETURN COUNT(x) LIMIT {limit}\", {limit:10000});")
public void deleteXyz(@Param("id") Long id);
```

The problem is that the execution has no effect (nothing is deleted) when executed programatically (e.g., in a unit test), but there are no errors either. When executing in the Web Interface, everything works fine.

All queries are enabled / whitelisted in the Neo4j config file.

Comment: could you please provide the neo4j config file? I have no parameters and still can't make it work. Executing the same query in the neo4j browser resolves just fine.

Answer (score 1):

In case somebody faces the same problem in the future, i figured it out:

It has something to do with the way the parameters are passed to the procedure / query: Instead of the above version use the following one:

```
@Query("CALL apoc.periodic.commit(\"MATCH (n:SomeNodeLabel)-[*]->(x) WHERE ID(n) = {id} DETACH DELETE x RETURN COUNT(x) LIMIT {limit}\", {limit:10000, id: {id}});")
public void deleteXyz(@Param("id") Long id);
```